# How to make specific record bold in custom edit form?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list.  When users are creating  a list item, I want certain field names to show in bold.

For example, when users are creating a new Task item, I want the records to become bold when a specific field with a special value appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Niloo.

You can apply conditional formatting for specific criteria in list item.
Please check below link for further information.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/apply-conditional-formatting-to-a-data-view-HA010099624.aspx